# Is there a way to separate files with folders in Pycharm (Python 3.6)?

Tags: python, file, directory, pycharm

[image]
Is there a way to put all the .jpg images into a folder while still allowing for my code to execute without issues? It would make organizing much easier, especially for larger projects.

When I do try to put them into a folder, my code does not execute because the .jpg files are in a separate folder from TypeRacerAutomation.py.

Any workarounds would be greatly appreciated! I want to have some ability to organize my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the path of the image.

For example. let's say you move all the images to an image folder then you can access them as follows:

```
typebox = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("images/image1.jpg", confidece=0.8)
```